# Qt C++ SerialPort is not receiving data

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying hard to solve this problem. But could not figure out what the problem is!
In Qt, C++ I tried to implement serial port write and read. It can only send data over serial, but not receiving from other end. I searched on google and StackOverFlow but could not solve it.
I installed virtual com port pair COM1<-->COM2

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QSerialPort>
#include <QDebug>

//QSerialPort *serial;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
 : QMainWindow(parent)
 , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);
 serial= new QSerialPort(this);
 serial->setPortName("COM1");
 serial->setBaudRate(QSerialPort::Baud9600);
 serial->setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
 serial->setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
 serial->setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
 serial->setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
 //serial->clearError();
 //serial->setDataTerminalReady(false);
 //serial->clear();
// qDebug() << "serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)";
 //serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
 if (serial->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
     {
          qDebug() << "Com port opened";
            // serial->setDataTerminalReady(false);
             serial->write("Hello");
     }
     else
     {
         qDebug() << "Not opened";
     }
  ui->label->setText("Waiting..");

 connect(serial,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(serialReceived()));
 connect(serial, SIGNAL(error(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)), this,SLOT(handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
 delete ui;
 serial->close();
}

void MainWindow::serialReceived(){

//QString received = this->Read();
//qDebug() << "received data:" << received;

 QByteArray ba;
 ba=serial->readAll();
 ui->label->setText("Waiting..");
 ui->label->setText(serial->readAll());

 qDebug()<<ba;
 qDebug() << "bytes available:" << serial->bytesAvailable();

}

void MainWindow::handleError(QSerialPort::SerialPortError error)
{
qDebug()<<"Error:"<<error;//I added this line
if(error==QSerialPort::ResourceError)
{
qDebug()<<"serial->errorString())";
//closeSerialPort();
}
}
```

COM1 is assigned in Qt code and COM2 is opened in a Serial Monitor.

To test, I wrote PythonQT code which is working fine but my requirement is c++

Comment: You are aware you're calling `serial->readAll()` twice in `MainWindow::serialReceived`? I suspect only the first will contain meaningful data.

Comment: Unrelated: Please stop using the Qt4 SIGNAL/SLOT syntax. The [new syntax](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) is safer and easier to type.

Comment: @Botje Yes i did that deliberately. First one does not give any data though.

Comment: @Botje I will update to new SIGNAL SLOT syntax. but this should also work!

Answer (score 1):

Even the Terminal example code supplied with Qt Creator is not sending or receiving data.

Answer (score 0):

you should firstly open wanted port，then  set  serilaport properties